# Did over 1000 people in Haiti report seeing Tupac a week after his death?

Tags: mortality, music

I stumbled upon this website http://thadrill.com/2013/03/1000-people-called-haiti-police-saying-they-saw-2pac-shukur/ that claimed over a 1000 people in Haiti reported to the police that they had seen Tupac.

I performed a quick Google search after, and it turns out this belief isn't uncommon. But I couldn't find any authoritative source that confirms it, so is it just another one of those urban myths?

Comment: Why would that many people /call the cops/ about this? Does Haiti have a policy of phoning in illegal ghosts?

Comment: @StarWeaver If saw a person who was established to be dead I'd probably phone the police